# Change file creation time on a FAT filesystem

Tags: filesystems, files, stat, fat

I need a way to change the **creation time** of a file on a mounted FAT32 volume. I have to do that because my MP3 player will only read files sorted by this creation time.

If I can find a way to set the file creation time (like `touch` can do with modification / access time) of a file, a trivial script will allow MP3 files to be read in the right order (as expected, alphabetically).

But I've yet to find a solution, and my searches have been in vain. I hope you guys can help me !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally ended up using [fatsort](http://fatsort.sourceforge.net/), which does the job nicely, and it's also a lot quicker than copying the files over and over.

Answer (score 6):

First thing that comes to mind is to `mv` the file(s) to a temporary, `cp` the temporary file to the old filename and delete the temporary.

I just made a fast check:

```
touch foo
ls -l foo
```

returns:

```
0 -rw-r--r-- 1 shunz shunz 0 2011-03-22 11:07 foo
```

wait some minutes and then:

```
mv foo bar
ls -l bar

0 -rw-r--r-- 1 shunz shunz 0 2011-03-22 11:07 bar
```

notice the creation time **isn't** modified, while:

```
cp bar foo
ls -l foo bar

0 -rw-r--r-- 1 shunz shunz 0 2011-03-22 11:07 bar
0 -rw-r--r-- 1 shunz shunz 0 2011-03-22 11:10 foo
```

now foo is created at current time!

**EDIT**

sorry, forgot to mention, tried this on a FAT32 formatted USB stick under Ubuntu.